# How to save decimal value in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

From the document I didn't see Decimal type support. How can I save decimal data in TDengine? Should I use varchar type (string type in TDengine)?

Answer (score 1):

TDengine definitely supports storing floating numbers as FLOAT/DOUBLE type columns. You can specify the column type when creating table, something like:

> create table tb (ts timestamp, col0 float, col1 double)

where col0 and col1 are columns created and can be used to store decimal values.

If you want to preserve decimal digits using string type(binary/nchar) is also a good choice and you can also use sql function cast to convert string values to numerical values.